# Extract method raw bytes

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

How to extract method raw bytes using ASM ?

I need a map of method signatures* and raw bytes

```java
ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(artifact.getInputStream(jarEntry));
classReader.accept(new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM9) {
    @Override
    public void visitEnd() {
        super.visitEnd(); 
        byte[] methodRawBytes = this.?                
    }
}, 0);
```

hacks/reflection-based answers are welcome

*Method signature in a ByteCode format like `Lcom/foo/CustomClass;->methodName(Ljava/lang/String;B)V`

Comment: Why would you need that? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It's not like there is a contiguous section of the class file that you can just take out and say "this is all the bytes for the method `foo`". Sure, there is the `method_info` structure that you can get, but the information in it will not make sense unless you also have the constant pool.

Comment: i'm trying to get all methods that contains a byte pattern

Comment: And *why* are you doing that? What does the byte pattern mean?

Comment: malware signature

Comment: Would it be too vague if you just searched for that byte sequence in the inputstream? or would you expect false positives?

Comment: not sure i understand, somehow ASM reads the .class and knows how to split into methods, i need raw bytes of a method (for all methods)

Answer (score 4):

The ASM library is not designed to provide you raw bytes. But it’s not so hard to write a dedicated class file parser for such an extraction task using the [documentation of the class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-4.html).

The bigger problem is the idea of performing a malware signature check on the method’s raw bytecode itself.

Consider the following self-contained example:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.HexFormat;

public class BytecodeSignature {
    static class Example1 extends BytecodeSignature {
        void method() throws IOException {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/sbin/whatever", new String[0]);
        }
    }
    static class Example2 extends BytecodeSignature {
        void method() throws IOException {
            System.console().printf("hello");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String methodName = "method";

        for(Class<?> c: BytecodeSignature.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
            System.out.println(c);
            ByteBuffer buf;
            try(InputStream is = c.getResourceAsStream(c.getName() + ".class")) {
              buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(is.readAllBytes());
            }
            buf.position(8);
            int codeCP = 0, methodNameCP = 0;
            for(int cp = 1, num = buf.getChar(); cp < num; cp++) {
                switch(buf.get()) {
                    default -> throw new IllegalStateException();
                    case Module, Package, Class, String, MethodType
                         -> buf.position(buf.position() + 2);
                    case FieldRef, MethodRef, IfMethodRef, NameAndType,
                         InvokeDynamic, ConstDynamic, Int, Float
                        -> buf.position(buf.position() + 4);
                    case Double, Long -> {buf.position(buf.position() + 8); cp++;}
                    case MethodHandle -> buf.position(buf.position() + 3);
                    case Utf8 -> {
                        if(lookingAt(buf, "Code")) codeCP = cp;
                        if(lookingAt(buf, methodName)) methodNameCP = cp;
                        buf.position(buf.getChar() + buf.position());
                    }
                }
            }
            if(codeCP == 0 || methodNameCP == 0) continue;

            buf.position(buf.position() + 6);
            buf.position(buf.getChar() + buf.position()); // skip interfaces
            for(int memberKind = 0; memberKind < 2; memberKind++) {
                int numMembers = buf.getChar(); // memberKind: 0 fields, 1 methods
                for(int m = 0; m < numMembers; m++) {
                    boolean targetMethod = memberKind != 0
                        && buf.getChar(buf.position() + 2) == methodNameCP;
                    buf.position(buf.position() + 6);
                    int numAttr = buf.getChar();
                    for(int a = 0; a < numAttr; a++) {
                        int name = buf.getChar(), length = buf.getInt();
                        if(targetMethod && name == codeCP) printCode(buf);
                        buf.position(buf.position() + length);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // ASCII only
    private static boolean lookingAt(ByteBuffer buf, String string) {
        int pos = buf.position();
        int num = buf.getChar(pos);
        if(num != string.length()) return false;
        pos += 2;
        for(int six = 0; six < num; six++, pos++)
            if(buf.get(pos) != string.charAt(six)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private static void printCode(ByteBuffer buf) {
        int offset = buf.arrayOffset() + buf.position() + 8;
        int length = buf.getInt(buf.position() + 4);
        System.out.println(HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ")
            .formatHex(buf.array(), offset, offset + length));
    }

    private static final byte Utf8 = 1, Int = 3, Float = 4, Long = 5, Double = 6,
        Class = 7, String = 8, FieldRef = 9, MethodRef = 10, IfMethodRef = 11,
        NameAndType = 12, MethodHandle = 15, MethodType = 16,
        ConstDynamic = 17, InvokeDynamic = 18, Module = 19, Package = 20;
}
```

This prints

```
class BytecodeSignature$Example1
b8 00 12 12 18 03 bd 00 1a b6 00 1c 57 b1

class BytecodeSignature$Example2
b8 00 12 12 18 03 bd 00 1a b6 00 1c 57 b1
```

when compiled with Eclipse and

```
class BytecodeSignature$Example2
b8 00 07 12 0d 03 bd 00 0f b6 00 11 57 b1

class BytecodeSignature$Example1
b8 00 07 12 0d 03 bd 00 0f b6 00 11 57 b1
```

when compiled with JDK 17’s javac.

Results may vary, but it does already demonstrates that the harmless

```java
System.console().printf("hello");
```

produces exactly the same bytecode as the potentially problematic

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/sbin/whatever", new String[0]);
```

when compiled with the same compiler, while the identical code may produce different bytecode when compiled with a different compiler. It may also differ depending on other conditions outside the method.

The reason is that the critical aspect of these methods is not the code structure (which is identical), but which classes, members, and string constants have been used and these artifacts are not stored in the method but in the constant pool.

Decoding the sequence `b8 00 12 12 18 03 bd 00 1a b6 00 1c 57 b1` yields

```
  0 invokestatic  [18]    // [7] with javac
  3 ldc           [24]    // [13] with javac
  5 iconst_0
  6 anewarray     [26]    // [15] with javac
  9 invokevirtual [28]    // [17] with javac
 12 pop
 13 return
```

Those differing numbers are indices into the constant pool. The indices depend on whether the constants are shared with other members, have been encountered before by the compiler, or whether the compiler has a sorting strategy for the constants.

But not on the actual value.

So you can’t tell these two methods apart by looking at the raw bytes and you can’t recognize an already known method by looking at the raw bytes (when subtle unrelated things changed).

There is no way around parsing the bytecode and incorporating the referenced constants. But the good news is, the ASM library has an API to do exactly that, decoding the instructions and the referenced constants for you…

Comment: Nice job finding two examples that compile into identical bytecode. Nicely shows that this approach is futile.

Answer (score 1):

I was curios, so I inspected the [code of the ASM `ClassReader` class](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/-/blob/master/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.java).

Obviously, the library understands the class file structure and "knows" where the actual bytecode lives.

However, it doesn't seem to expose that raw information to the caller, but only allows visiting individual bytecode instructions.

The relevant (internal) method is [`ClassReader.readCode`](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/-/blob/master/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.java#L1535). As far as I know after

```
final int bytecodeStartOffset = currentOffset;
final int bytecodeEndOffset = currentOffset + codeLength;
```

`bytecodeStartOffset` and `bytecodeEndOffset` hold the limits of the code attribute you seem to be interested in, but those (and the underlying `byte[]`) don't get exposed to the caller directly.

You could try to patch the method to invoke some kind new of `visitRawCode` method on the visitor and/or request such a feature from the project. But as it stands, that doesn't seem to be a supported feature.

Comment: Thank you. Reading classBuffer from bytecodeStartOffset to bytecodeEndOffset does not return the method's raw bytes

Comment: @whoopdedoo: how did you verify? And what exactly do you mean by "method's raw bytes"? Because it should return exactly the content of the `code` array in the [`Code` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3) of the method. That's where the actual bytecode is. If you need anything else (like the whole `Code` attribute), then that should be findable within this method (or its callers) as well.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the entire `method_info` structure instead?